# Selenium & Chromedriver - PHP Webdrivers lack correct quit method, just close() - what wire protocol commands do other languages like Java send?

Tags: php, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

If I wanted to achieve what Selenium's Java Webdriver does when it uses it's **quit()** method with **Chrome**/Chromedriver - but by modifying a PHP Webdriver - or any language, I just want the concept - **how would I do it**?

**Is it a JSON wire protocol command or something else?** I can find no mention of "quit"  in the wire protocol docs and when I try to send the quit command the way the python source seems to (command.py) - no luck. Versions - I installed the newest of all in the last month (Selenium, Chromediver, chrome, php webdrivers - Element34's mostly but examined Facebook's and Nearsoft's).

***-------Context:-------------------------------------***

If you repeatedly launch chrome with a Webdriver session and use the close method (which sends a wire protocol "DELETE" command) - the next time you try to open a session odds are good it will say chrome closed incorrectly and it won't function: "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". So automated testing is dead - you have to launch and close chrome manually.

**I read here that the thing to do is to use the quit method instead of the close method. However** 1) there is no quit command in my Php Webdriver (element34) and the other two either don't have a quit() method or they send the same command for both close and quit: "DELETE" with the wire protocol. If I read the python webdriver code correctly it sends "quit" instead of "delete" but that doesn't work when I try it in Php.

Any help or even just illumination on whether quit is a selenium communication or somehow it's unique to Chrome would be helpful... not sure what's going on since I don't see quit mentioned in Selenium's docs.

Answer (score 0):

JsonWireProtocol command is: [DELETE /session/:sessionId](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#DELETE_/session/:sessionId)